# Hiding button's label in narrow version of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on responsive version of new app and recognised that when page is displayed on the  narrow version the buttons and drop-downs in `top navbar` just are moved under other items.

My dreamed situation in such case would be just replacing ie:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i> Very long label of this button</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i></a>
```

Can I achieve this with 'raw' Bootstrap?

The only idea I have now is to incorporate `jQuery` and toggling the visibility of link's label (ie. after wrapping with span) with `resize()` event

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="icon-flag"></i> <span>Very long label of this button</span></a>
```

#### Answers for comments and conclusion

Although I didn't specified it before, my intention is to keep possibility of custom setting the break-points. That's why I asked about `narrow version` and not about `phone`, `tablet` and `desktop` selectors. Of course default selectors in most cases will be OK, however `media queries` gives me additional flexibility, which I will need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved with the default [Bootstrap's responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive):

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i>
      <span class="hidden-phone">Very long label of this button</span></a>
```

If that doesn't meet your needs, you can use `media queries` to set the label to `display:none;` as you need

```
<a class="target_el" href="#"><i class="icon-flag">
      </i><span>Very long label of this button</span></a>

@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:320px)
{
    .target_el span { display:none; }
}
```

else you would have to go the jQuery route.

Comment: Incredible things :) Thank you

Comment: This is not a nice solution. Media queries should be used as little as possible. Twitter Bootstrap provides classes that do all the work. Check the other answer. cc @biesior

Comment: @merv: you should not downvote the answer as it's that what I preffer in my case. Check my edited question. Sherbrow's answer is also good for me in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the classes `.hidden-phone` or `.visible-desktop` or `.visible-tablet` (check the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)) to hide or display any element on certain resolutions.

You really shouldn't use `@media` queries for that since those classes are provided.

Comment: Lokase's answer is right for me, check my edited question. Of course your solution also will be helpful in other cases.